# Difference between fflush and fsync

Tags: fflush, fsync, c, windows

I thought `fsync()` does `fflush()` internally, so using `fsync()` on a stream is OK. But I am getting an unexpected result when executed under network I/O.

My code snippet:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(file, "wb");
/* multiple fputs() calls like: */
fputs(buf, fp);
...
...
fputs(buf.c_str(), fp);
/* get fd of the FILE pointer */
fd = fileno(fp);
#ifndef WIN32
ret = fsync(fd);
#else
ret = _commit(fd);
fclose(fp);
```

But it seems `_commit()` is not flushing the data (I tried on Windows and the data was written on a Linux exported filesystem).

When I changed the code to be:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(file, "wb");
/* multiple fputs() calls like: */
fputs(buf, fp);   
...   
...
fputs(buf.c_str(), fp);
/* fflush the data */
fflush(fp);
fclose(fp);
```

it flushes the data.

I am wondering if `_commit()` does the same thing as `fflush()`. Any inputs?

Comment: What is the problem you were seeing with the first example?

Comment: @rogerdpack in first example, writing to stream through fputs() is not synching / committing to disk even if calling _commit() function on the fd (file descriptor). This test was done under cluster system where the remote linux filesystem is exported as CIFS and used on Windows machine and node failover is tested during write. When node recovers it has been found that file size is zero.

Comment: Where is `#endif`?

Comment: The question was internally consistent, and the answers consistent with it, prior to revision #5, which fundamentally changed the nature of the question.  Rolled back to revision #4.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`fflush()` works on `FILE*`, it just flushes the internal buffers in the `FILE*` of your application  out to the OS.

`fsync` works on a lower level, it tells the OS to flush its buffers to the physical media.

OSs heavily cache data you write to a file. If the OS enforced every write to hit the drive, things would be *very* slow. `fsync` (among other things) allows you to control when the data should hit the drive.

Furthermore, fsync/commit works on a file descriptor. It has no knowledge of a `FILE*` and can't flush its buffers. `FILE*` lives in your application, file descriptors live in the OS kernel, typically.

Comment: Thanks i was thinking on the same line. So if we are using FILE* then the same can be achieved by fflush() followed by fsync().

Comment: No, because you cannot `fsync` a `FILE*`.

Comment: @patrickvacek actually you can get the file descriptor from `FILE *` using `int fileno(FILE * stream);` from `stdio.h`.

Comment: @jotik: You should use *either* (standard) `FILE *` functions, *or* (operating system) file handles. You don't mix them. And `fileno()` is not a standard function. Unfortunately, people have been notoriously lax with "expanding" standard headers...

Comment: @DevSolar - `fileno()` is part of the POSIX standard, so although it's not necessarily portable, it is standard on some platforms.

Answer (score 12):

The standard C function `fflush()` and the POSIX system call `fsync()`  are conceptually somewhat similar. `fflush()` operates on C file streams (`FILE` objects), and is therefore portable.
`fsync()` operate on POSIX file descriptors.
Both cause buffered data to be sent to a destination.

On a POSIX system, each C file stream [has an associated file descriptor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fileno.html), and all the operations on a C file stream will be implemented by delegating, when necessary, to POSIX system calls that operate on the file descriptor.

One might think that a call to `fflush` on a POSIX system would cause a `write` of any data in the buffer of the file stream, followed by a call of `fsync()` for the file descriptor of that file stream. So on a POSIX system there would be no need to follow a call to `fflush` with a call to `fsync(fileno(fp))`. But is that the case: is there a call to `fsync` from `fflush`?

No, calling `fflush` on a POSIX system does not imply that `fsync` will be called.

The C standard for `fflush` says (emphasis added) it

> causes any unwritten data for [the] stream to be delivered to the host environment *to be written* to the file

Saying that the data is *to be* written, rather than that is *is* written implies that further buffering by the host environment is permitted. That buffering by the "host environment" could include, for a POSIX environment, the internal buffering that `fsync` flushes. So a close reading of the C standard suggests that the standard does not require the POSIX implementation to call `fsync`.

The [POSIX standard description of `fflush`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fflush.html) does not declare, as an [extension of the C semantics](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/help/codes.html#CX), that `fsync` is called.

Answer (score 4):

`fflush()` and `fsync()` can be used to try and ensure data is written to the storage media (but it is not always be possible):

1. first use `fflush(fp)` on the output stream (`fp` being a `FILE *` obtained from `fopen` or one of the standard streams `stdout` or `stderr`) to write the contents of the buffer associated with the stream to the OS.
2. then use `fsync(fileno(fp))` to tell the OS to write its own buffers to the storage media.

Note however that `fileno()` and `fsync()` are POSIX functions that might not be available on all systems, notably Microsoft legacy systems where alternatives may be named `_fileno()`, `_fsync()` or `_commit()`...

Comment: This is the only answer that explains the full process which requires calling both `fflush` and `fsync` so I like this answer the best.

Answer (score 2):

I could say that for simplicity:

use `fsync()` with not streaming files (integer file descriptors)

use `fflush()` with file streams.

Also here is the help from man:

```
int fflush(FILE *stream); // flush a stream, FILE* type

int fsync(int fd); // synchronize a file's in-core state with storage device
                    // int type
```

Comment: So does `fflush()` implicitly call `fsync()` for you?

Comment: @binki no - it calls `write()` on the buffered data

Comment: Ah, it looks like the question was edited to ask the wrong thing and it was fixed after I looked at it (when I looked at it the question was “does `fflush()` call `fsync()` for you?, now it’s back to the nonsensical “does `fsync()` call `fflush()` for you which is impossible because you can map a `FILE*` onto an `fd` but not map an `fd` to a `FILE*`). So @Guillaume, you’re saying that one would need to do `fflush()` and *then* `fsync()` (<del>unless you’re about to `fclose()` which will do both for you anyway</del>, oh, `fclose()` doesn’t automatically flush, xD).

Comment: @binki if you want to make sure all written data (written by both buffered and unbuffered I/O) is on the physical media backing the file.  You would need to both call `fflush()` and `fsync()`, yes.  In general people that care about that do not use buffered I/O (using `setvbuf()` for example) so they usually just do a `fsync()`.

Answer (score 1):

To force the commitment of recent changes to disk, use the sync() or fsync() functions.

***fsync()*** will synchronize all of the given file's data and metadata with the permanent storage device. It should be called just before the corresponding file has been closed.

***sync()*** will commit all modified files to disk.

Comment: We are discussing difference b/w fsync Vs fflush

Answer (score 1):

I think below document from python (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) clarifies it very well.

> os.fsync(fd) Force write of file with filedescriptor fd to disk. On
>   Unix, this calls the native fsync() function; on Windows, the MS
>   _commit() function.
>
> If you’re starting with a Python file object f, first do f.flush(),
>   and then do os.fsync(f.fileno()), to ensure that all internal buffers
>   associated with f are written to disk.
>
> Availability: Unix, and Windows starting in 2.2.3.