# stdout redirecting

Tags: c, redirect, stream, stdout

If I make a `dup` of the `stdout` stream (in order to use it later) and make `freopen` of the `stdout` stream to the file and then `printf("data")`, the file is not updated immediately with data. It is updated only after I perform `fflush(stdout)`.

Does the `fflush(stdout)` have some additional side effects?

Is there some more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single call to the C89 `setvbuf()` to avoid cluttering your code with `fflush()`'s. Or maybe the wrapper `setlinebuf()`.

But all of the above just flush the buffers. You may need to use `fsync()`.

Comment: Another edit: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340610/difference-between-fflush-and-fsync/2340641#2340641 for `fflush` vs `fsync`.

Comment: Using `setvbuf()` with `_IOLBF` is normally sufficient - unless you have very unusual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior in buffered I/O. Nothing strange should happen with a flush.

However, you shouldn't be messing with stdout in this case. Open your file with `fopen`, you'll get a `FILE` pointer. Use this pointer in functions like `fprintf` to print directly in it, and flush it if you need immediate results. Don't forget to close the file with `fclose` when you're done.

Comment: He might not have the source code for the parts that call printf.