# fsync does not write data to file

Tags: c, fsync

I have two (POSIX) threads that write to a log file like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&log_mutex);
fprintf(LOG, "something...\n");
fsync(fileno(LOG));
pthread_mutex_unlock(&log_mutex);
```

The file is opened in `main()` with `fopen()` with mode "a". While the process is running I can't see anything appearing in the file with `cat` or `tail` although after the process is terminated and the file is `fclose()`-ed, the lines are all there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe [you want to use fflush()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340610/difference-between-fflush-and-fsync)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you need to call `fflush()` to flush the changed to the file system.

See also [difference between fsync() and fflush()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340641/145013).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using FILE handle in C, you need to first flush the data from C/C++ buffers to kernel buffers by calling fflush().  fsync is not really required unless you also want to make sure the data reaches the underlying physical storage especially for durability concerns