# fflush or sync need after boost::filesystem::copy?

Tags: synchronization, copy, boost-filesystem, fflush, fsync

I have a problem when using boot library for copying files. After copying a file, sometimes the file size if 0kb.

Here is my code:

```
boost::filesystem::copy("from.txt", "to.txt");
```

I just want to know whether should I call `sync()`, `fsync()`, or  `fflush()` for that?

As far as I know, only stream based i/o needs `fflush()` to guarantee the file writing but, I cannot find the reference documentation about `boost::filesystem::copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found that an answer by myself. 
boost::filesystem::copy() did not need flush(). but it needs sync() when you want to put them in your flash explicitly.

[Difference between fflush and fsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340610/difference-between-fflush-and-fsync)