# No output from iosnoop (dtrace) until application is killed

Tags: c, dtrace

I want to understand iosnoop. Therefor I wrote a small program to trace on. I expect to see something in iosnoop if I flush the cache. I don't see anything until I kill the application. What am I doing wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid: %lun", pid);

    FILE *file = fopen("hanswurst.txt", "a");

    while(1){
        fputs("Hello\n", file);
        fflush(file);
        sleep(1);
    }


    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, at least on macOS, `iosnoop` only monitors OS I/O events to hardware. The `fflush()` call only flushes the C API file I/O buffer to the OS buffers, but until your file is closed, nothing is written to disk.

You could add a `fsync(fileno(file));` after the `fflush()` to tell the OS to write its buffers to disk.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340641 for details.

Alternatively, if you want to see what happens with the program without `fsync()`, you could use `dtruss` instead of `iosnoop`. It will show the system calls of your program while they are happening and will show the `write` calls to the OS.